# How do I prevent NSMutableDictionary from converting my long NSString to NSNumber upon initWithContentsOfFile?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In our code we do the following:

```
- (void) createComment:(NSString *)comment ForId:(NSString *)objectId
{    
  [facebookArguments setObject:objectId forKey:FACEBOOK_COMMENTS_FOR_ID_KEY ];
  [facebookArguments setObject:comment forKey:FACEBOOK_COMMENTS_FOR_ID_COMMENT]; 
  [facebookPrefs writeToFile:facebookPrefsFilePath atomically: NO];
  [facebookArguments writeToFile:facebookArgumentsFilePath atomically:NO];
}
```

but upon calling this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* fbArgsDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: facebookArgumentsFilePath];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", fbArgsDic);
```

Here's the Log output before:

```
2011-08-04 16:11:53.938 My_App[30909:207] Dictionary: {
    facebookGetCommentsForIdComment = Legend;
    facebookGetCommentsForIdKey = 10150249987646875;
    facebookLikeForIdKey = 10150249445616875;
}
```

And After:

```
2011-08-04 16:06:39.685 My_App[30693:207] Dictionary: {
    facebookGetCommentsForIdComment = Legend;
    facebookGetCommentsForIdKey = "1.015024998764688e+16";
    facebookLikeForIdKey = 10150249445616875;
}
```

It's converted the FACEBOOK_COMMENTS_FOR_ID_KEY entry, which was a NSString as seen above, into a NSNumber and lost some digits. These are LONG numbers as they are facebook id's.

Any idea what's going on and how we can fix it?

Comment: Why didn't you post the log output? And an example ID.

Comment: I think you shouldn't call that string 'id', since it's a reserved keyword. Not sure if it's the problem though

Comment: I think `facebookGetCommentsForIdKey` dictionary is autoreleased. Tried using `retain`??

Comment: It happens even if I name it differently. And facebookGetCommentsForIdKey is a constant defined in FACEBOOK_COMMENTS_FOR_ID_KEY? can that realease? I mean it's the right number, it's just being converted to exponential format and losing digits in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary should be getting serialized as a properly list, which should preserve types.  Are you sure `id` is really an `NSString` to start with?  (Also, I agree with other commenters that you should use a different variable name to avoid confusing with the type `id`.)

One possibility is that it's actually an `NSDecimalNumber`, which gets written out as a numeric type and parsed back in as an `NSNumber`, losing precision.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"Class of id: %@", NSStringFromClass([id class]));
```

And if it is a numeric type after all, you can do:

```
[facebookArguments setObject:[id stringValue] forKey:FACEBOOK_COMMENTS_FOR_ID_KEY];
```

Comment: You sir, win an internet. I thought the method signature would enforce NSString* for me. Not so. Also renamed the variable. Thanks.

Comment: I presume you're getting that number from a JSON or XML parser, and the method that gives you that value is typed `id`, which means "this variable is dynamically typed". I highly recommend you explicitly check the actual type of any value you get from the internet with e.g. `[val isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]` to catch any type inconsistencies. That way if the web API has a bug and gives you the wrong type, you can handle the situation gracefully instead of crashing. (I learned this from painful experience with the Etsy API.)

Comment: It's the facebook fql API through the facebook library. Oh well.